# AngularJS, Catch a response from a service and use it in a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have created a service and I have a responce, but I don't know how to use that responce into a controller.

The service that I have:

```
angular
.module('MyApp')
.service('telForm', function($http){
  this.getAll = function(success, failure){
      $http.get('https://service.com.mx/telehone')
        .success(success)
        .error(failure);
  }
})
// the answer is 
{
"telehone": "12121212",
"token": "760619"
}
```

The controller that I want to contruct: (moreless)

```
var1 = "telephone";
var2 = "token";

$http({
    method:'POST',
    url:"http://www.example-server.com/" + telephone + "/" + token + "/example",
    data : {
      phone: $scope.phone,
      company: $scope.company,
      contract: '1',
      privacy: '1',
      email: $scope.email
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You have 2 API calls (one in service and another one in controller), which do not relate to eachother in any way.

Comment: Just a note: don't use `success` and `error` methods, they're deprecated. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the methods `success` and `error` are deprecated, as you can check on this [deprecation notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice):

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead. If `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` is set to `false` then these methods will throw `$http/legacy` error.

You can simply return a promise from your service and then do what you want in your controller, as the following:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, telForm) {
      $scope.response = '';
      $scope.doGet = function() {
        telForm.doGet().then(
          function(response) {
            $scope.response = 'success';
            // $scope.services = response.data;
          },
          function(response) {
            $scope.response = 'error';
          });
      }

      $scope.doPost = function() {
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: "http://www.example-server.com/" + telephone + "/" + token + "/example",
          data: {
            phone: $scope.phone,
            company: $scope.company,
            contract: '1',
            privacy: '1',
            email: $scope.email
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });
      }
    })

  .service('telForm', function($http) {
    function doGet() {
      // return promise from test
      return $http.get('http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?');
    }

    return {
      doGet: doGet
    }
  })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  Response: <span ng-bind="response"></span>
  <hr>
  <button type="button" ng-click="doGet()">Request</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
.service('myService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var getAll = function (url, callback) {
        $http.get(url)
            .success(function (response) {
                callback(response);
            })
            .error(function (err) {
                callback(err);
            })
    }
    return {
        getAll:getAll
    }
}]);
```

Then in your controller you call the service like so

```
.controller('myController', ['myService', function (myService) {
    myService.getAll('http://...', function (response) {
            // do something with the response
        })

}]);
```